# Как динамически добавить большой контент на страницу с помощью jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь динамически формировать html страницу на jQuery. Пишу, грубо говоря, так:

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    $('#content').append('<div>'+array[i]+'</div>');
    //также пробовал .html()
}
```

Здесь в массиве array содержится огромное количество элементов, содержащих текст. После выполнения кода на странице появляются не все div'ы, но после обновления страницы начинают отображаться все. Как будто блоки не успевают "прорисоваться". При этом когда блоки не отображаются, они всё равно видны в коде страницы. Как возможно решить эту проблему?
*P.S. Ответ "выводи контент на php" не подойдёт. Это приложение на Cordova, и здесь так или иначе приходится формировать страницы на JS.*

Comment: Пробуй грузить с отсечкой в 200мс каждые там 2-5-10-100 блоков, в зависимости от того, насколько большой объем информации они в себе хранят. Просто, пока грузится контент, добавь футером спиннер какойнибудь. Главное грузануть контент, который поместится во вьюпорте, остальное можно и с задержкой

Answer (score 3):

Добавление элемента в DOM - ресурсоемкая операция. Формируйте массив дивов, потом добавляйте целиком все элементы

```
$('#content').append(divs.join(''));
```

Например так:

```
$('#content').append(array.map(function (el) {
    return '<div>' + el + '</div>';
}).join(''));
```

Comment: сделал как в вашем примере. ничего не изменилось. кстати вы потеряли закрывающуюся круглую скобку после join('')

Comment: @AlMr Есть такой грех - потерял. Писал с сильно тормозящего планшета. Покажите как вы получаете массив `array`, сколько там элементов и сколько выводится (хотя бы какая часть в %)

Comment: Получаю JSON-файл с записями с сервера. Затем получаю массив методом JSON.parse(); Кстати проблема решена. Формирую строку content в которую помещаю все дивы и затем по таймауту с задержкой в 1 секунду кидаю сразу всё на страницу. Так всё прорисовывается.

Comment: @AlMr Странное решение. Секунда это как бы дофига в работе интерфейса. Покажите, все-таки, как получаете JSON